# Inserting NULL value with Ecto.Repo.update_all/3

Tags: postgresql, elixir, ecto

Suppose we have a table called `users` with a nullable column `permission_set_id`, which is a foreign key to another table called `permission_sets`, achieved with a `Ecto.Schema.belongs_to/3` (docs [here](https://hexdocs.pm/ecto/Ecto.Schema.html#belongs_to/3)) macro. I need to nullify that field with such query:

```
query = from u in User,
        where: u.id == ^user_id

case Repo.update_all(query, set: [permission_set_id: nil]) do
  {1, _terms} -> send_resp(conn, :no_content, "")
  {0, _terms} -> send_resp(conn, :not_found, "User not found.")
end
```

However this unit test fails:

```
test "unassigns user's permission set", %{conn: conn} do
  user = Factory.insert(:user)
  permission_set = Factory.insert(:permission_set, user_id: user.id)
  tight_user = Factory.insert(:user, permission_set_id: permission_set.id)

  conn = delete conn, user_user_permission_set_path(conn, :delete, user)

  query = from u in User,
    where: u.id == ^tight_user.id,
    select: u.permission_set_id

  assert response(conn, 204)
  refute Repo.one(query)
end
```

with the result

```
test unassigns user's permission set (SpheriumWebService.UserPermissionSetControllerTest)
test/controllers/user_permission_set_controller_test.exs:96

Expected false or nil, got 94
code: Repo.one(query)
stacktrace:
  test/controllers/user_permission_set_controller_test.exs:108: (test)
```

I tried setting the value to `fragment("NULL")` instead, found I could not use it there. Values `:null`, `:nilify` and `false` are not working though, says it could not cast it to integer value.

Any ideas? I have checked [tests](https://github.com/elixir-ecto/ecto/blob/master/test/ecto/repo_test.exs), but found nothing close so far.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like a simple mistake in the tests.

You are creating two users:

- `user` (probably factory assigns it permissions)
- `tight_user` (where you assign permissions explicitly)
- delete permissions from `user`
- query for `tight_users` permissions and expect it to be nil while you never deleted it, because you were deleting `user` permissions.

Comment: Ouch, let me make a clarification: The permission set foreign key in user is optional (nullable). If you won't asslgn anything explicitly, factory will remain it NULL. The user foreign key in the permission is not optional though, since every permission set needs to be created by a user and this field refers to creator of it.